# php code for save all button

Tags: php, button, save, x-editable

s there a button we can add to the top of the grid to save all the data entry changes made in the table./Grid.?

I have a Delete/Save all the way to the right of the screen on each record, however this is not a desirable position for our data entry personnel.

How can we save all the changes at one time?

Thx -Patrick

Comment: What grid library are you using?

Comment: I don't know if I understand your problem, but You can just make a form with POST method, and send all data using <input type="submit"> for example and then do something on the server side.

Comment: Hi Barmar, i'm using an editable grid in Scriptcase, we are adding the new monthly rates to the database. We enter 20 or more records at one time each month. i have a save and delete button for each of the records, but think it would be easier for them to enter new rates tabbing thru the feilds and then click on a save all button at the top. Scriptcase said I have to create my php or java code for the new button.

Comment: <input name="Save" type="submit" class="button" value="Save">
This code isn't working properly